# Prove the continuity of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, piecewise-continuity

everyone. I have a question of proving the continuity of a piecewise function.

This question is from `Patrick M.Fitzpatrick, <Advanced Calculus, 2nd edition>`

**Problem**

Exercise 4 of the exercises for section 3.6 `Images and Inverses, monotone functions`, Chapter 3 `Continuous functions`:

Define

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x-1, & \text{if x < 0} \\
x+1, & \text{if x >= 0}
\end{cases}
$

Show that $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing and that $f^{-1}: f(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x=1$.

**What I know and My solution**

It is simple to prove that $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing, thus I omit this step here. To show the inverse function $f^{-1}: f(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x=1$, I apply Theorem 3.29:

Theorem 3.29: Let *I* be an interval and suppose that the function $f: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotone. Then the inverse function $f^{-1}: f(I) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

*Proof*

Obviously, the function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, which is an interval, and it is strictly increasing. Theorem 3.29 asserts that the inverse function$f^{-1}: f(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Hence, the inverse function is continuous at $x = 1$. $\Box$

**My Question**

The inverse function is:

$
f^{-1}(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1, & \text{if x < -1} \\
x-1, & \text{if x >= 1}
\end{cases}
$

***How to show the inverse function is continuous at $x=1$ by the definition of continuity or by $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion rather than using Theorem 3.29?***

The definition of continuity at a point: The function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ in the domain *D* provided that for a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in *D*, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$, if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}x_n=x_0$.

The $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion at a point: A function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to satisfy the $\epsilon-\delta$ criterion at a point $x_0$ in the domain *D* provided that for each positive number $\epsilon$, there is a positive number $\delta$ such that for $x$ in *D*, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you find $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy Yes, I have. I add the inverse function $f^{-1}$ to the question. Wait for a moment.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy Hi! I have edit my question, please check it again. Thank you.

Comment: @zchenkui There seems to be a typo in the domain of your definition of $f^{-1}$; you mean 1 not $-1$? Also, that function isn't continuous at 1.

Comment: @Oliver Jones it's correct. The problem here is that $x<1$ is not in the domain of definition of f

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Isn't $f$ defined on ${\Bbb R}$?

Comment: Nope, it is not defined on $(-1,1)$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I think you mean the range, not domain.

Comment: @zchenkui You only need to investigate the one-sided continuity of $f^{-1}$ at $x=1$, and this follows from the continuity of $x-1$.

Comment: @Oliver Jones what is $f^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan We're talking at cross purposes. I agree that the domain of $f^{-1}$ doesn't include $(-1,1)$. What I'm saying is that in your comments you keep referring to $f$, not $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @OliverJones Thank you for your comment. I think the inverse function is correct. Its domain can be determined by the original function. Also, it is simple to prove the continuity of $f^{-1}$ at $x=1$ if only investigating the half domain $[1, \infty)$. But I wonder why I only need to check the half domain rather than the whole one $(-\infty, -1)\cup[1, \infty)$.

Comment: @zchenkui I don't understand your question. Continuity is a point-wise question; it has nothing to do with an interval.